# find twit from public twitter that contain phone number

Tags: search, twitter, url-encoding

I would like to know what kind of query search should I use to find twit that contain phone number from twitter api v 1.1.

i.g. I want to find twit that contain specific term i.e. "car" and also phone number that start with "08" which is the phone number length is 12 digit

I have been searching for this answer since yesterday, but did not lucky yet.

thank in advance

Comment: What searches have you already tried?

Comment: @terence-eden I try https://twitter.com/search?q=08%2B%5B0-9%5D%7B10%7D&src=typd